# How do i use hts() to aggregate a time series data?

Tags: r

I an new to R and have very basic doubts,

```
Company Customer    Product  Q1 Q2  Q3  Q4
xyz Customer1   ProductA    500 600 400 800
xyz Customer1   ProductB    100 255 520 642
xyz Customer1   ProductC    846 566 320 54
xyz Customer1   ProductD    510 53  100 210
xyz Customer2   ProductX    500 50  466 260
xyz Customer2   ProductY    100 120 150 620
xyz Customer2   ProductZ    500 460 240 543
```

The above mentioned is an example of my data set. I need to create a hierarchical time series using hts() with 3 levels. The bottom level (level 0) should contain the products(column - product) which will be aggregated to an upper level (level 1) which is based on customers (colunm - Customer) which inturn will have to be aggregated to the top level based on company.

My ques are,

- how do i write a hts() code for this data set?
- the data type of my data set is data frames, should i convert to
  matrix before using?

Comment: What is `hts()`?

Comment: Hts is a package created by Mr.Hyndman for hierarchical forecasting . Refer :https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/hts.pdf

Comment: Did you take a look at this [book](https://www.otexts.com/fpp2/)? This [part](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html) in particular.

Comment: Yea, i am referreing that book, I understood the example in that book but i dont know how to specify the node and character argument for my data set.

Comment: How much R experience do you have? If you do `?hts` you will be linked to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hts/versions/5.1.5/topics/hts. This has an example and information on the structure of the data e.g. it says the main data needs to be `A matrix or multivariate time series contain the bottom level series.`

Comment: to be honest, i am completely new to R. I imported the data from excel which is of datatype - data frame. i changes it to marix using <y=data.matrix(dataset, rownames.force = NA)>. is that correct?